# Move files from multiple folders to multiple folders in Linux

Tags: bash, file, move, directory

How can I move files from multiple folders to another location. For example if I have 3 folders with name /test/folder1, /test/folder2, /test/folder3  and I want to move the contents of these folders into another location like /temp/folder1, /temp/folder2 /temp/folder3 using a script. I do not want to move these folders, instead I want to move the files inside these folders. Please Help

Comment: You get to do it one folder at a time or with something like cpio/pax copy-through modes or possibly rsync.

Comment: Possibly `rsync -ax --progress --remove-source-files /test /temp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
cd test
for dir in folder*; do
    mv "$dir/*" "/temp/$dir"
done
```